# C static library uses function with external library

Tags: c, mingw

I create a library that contains a function that uses an external library. When i try to build the test application including all librarys i got `undefined reference error to PlaySoundA@12`. What is false in my development?

Following shows what i have do:

### **Step 1** - *Overview of function with external reference*

This is the audio_functions.c file

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Mmsystem.h> //For PlaySound() - Winmm.lib is library
#include "audio_functions.h"
uint8_t play_sound(const char *path)
{   
    int psret;
    psret = PlaySound(path, NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT | SND_NOSTOP);
    if(psret) { return 1; }
    else { return 0; }
}
```

This is only a simple function to test the case with external references.

### **Step 2** - *Creating library*

I use an .bat file for creating library

```
set pname=_ERZ_LIBRARY
set location=C:\MinGW\bin\proj\%pname%

//Creating .o files
//only in audio_functions is an external referance, the other functions works
gcc -c -pedantic %location%\audio_functions\*.c     -o %location%\_AR\audio_functions.o
... more files

cd %location%\_AR\
//Use ar.exe to create archiv from all .o files where created
ar -rcs %location%\BUILD\ERZ_LIBRARY.lib *.o

//Take a look to all functions in library
nm --print-armap %location%\BUILD\ERZ_LIBRARY.lib
```

The functions was archived, this is the output:

```
audio_functions.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .eh_frame
00000000 r .rdata$zzz
00000000 t .text
00000000 T _play_sound
         U _PlaySoundA@12
```

### **Step 3** - *Using library*

Following shows the test_erz_library.c (To use the created static library)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include "C:/MinGW/bin/proj/_ERZ_LIBRARY/ERZ_LIBRARY.h"
int main()
{
    output(blue, NULL, "TEST -- [Version %s]", "1.0.0"); //function from ERZ_LIBRARY that works
    get_version(1); //function from ERZ_LIBRARY that works
    
    play_sound("C:\\MinGW\\bin\\proj\\test_erz_library\\Aramam.wav"); //function from ERZ_LIBRARY that do not work and printing the undefined reference error
}
```

Next shows how i use the compiler (.bat file):

```
set val=test_erz_library
set pname=test_erz_library
gcc C:\MinGW\bin\proj\%pname%\%val%.c -lWinmm -LC:\MinGW\bin\proj\_ERZ_LIBRARY\BUILD -l:ERZ_LIBRARY.lib -o C:\MinGW\bin\proj\%pname%\%val%.exe
C:\MinGW\bin\proj\%pname%\%val%.exe
```

Without my `play_sound` function, all functions from my library works. When i use `play_sound`, the described error will generating..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **SOLUTION**

Just before posting i found a solution. The chronological order was my problem. When i compile like this

```
gcc C:\MinGW\bin\proj\%pname%\%val%.c -LC:\MinGW\bin\proj\_ERZ_LIBRARY\BUILD -l:ERZ_LIBRARY.lib -lWinmm -o C:\MinGW\bin\proj\%pname%\%val%.exe
```

all references where found. This is a little bit confusing but i hope my solution help people with the same problem.

Comment: Yes, the order in which libraries and other objects are listed on the linker command line is significant to many linkers.  Generally unresolved references in a given object will be resolved only against libraries that are listed after them.